# Windows 2000 Inaccessible Boot Device when running setup from SATA Hard Drive

Tags: hard-disk, windows

I have a MS-DOS 7.10 install on my SATA hard drive (BIOS set to IDE compat mode), and so I copied over the Windows 2000 install files and ran `i386/winnt.exe`.  It copies over the files fine, but when it restarts and runs setup, it stops for a few seconds at ‘Setup is Starting Windows 2000’, before BSODing with code 0x00007B: `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`. What’s going on? I think it may have to do with drivers and it not having the proper drivers to read the hard drive, but I’m not sure.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic. It's a question about Windows 2000.

Comment: This is not about retrocomputing.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 this is obviously off-topic. This OS while unsupported, can run on modern hardware and the question specifically asks about modern hardware.

Comment: @Anixx So can Windows 98 (if you reduce the OS-accessible memory / modify the memory manager), but _that's_ on-topic.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 for one, pointing to an only marginally related OS does not make a point, more important, It already requires, as you mention, additional steps to do so, which is not the case for W2k (AFAICT).

Comment: @Anixx This is obviously on-topic. Given that the accepted answer is known, we know the conditions for this error could have been reproduced with period-appropriate hardware, e.g. using a hardware RAID controller. The asker happens to have hit them with modern hardware, but this is all about how a retro OS interacts with a retro hardware interface, both of which are within scope.

Comment: @user3840170 no. Windows 2000 simply has out-of-box limitation on drive size, regardless of hardware, modern or not. There are available bootCDs available on the net whith this thing fixed. It was not a big issue when Win2000 was popular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that your SATA HDD is larger than ~128GB, therefore necessitating LBA48 addressing. Windows 2000 supports LBA48 as of Service Pack 3, but it's NOT enabled by default.

If your installation medium is at least Service Pack 3, you can manually enable LBA48 support by adding/editing this registry key:

`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Atapi\Parameters\EnableBigLba`

It is a DWORD value which needs to be set to '1'.

In order to make registry changes on a non-booting OS, you'll need another machine which can run a registry editor such as REGEDT32.EXE. The relevant registry hive to be edited in this case is `WINNT\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEM`.

Be aware that you can also modify the installation files themselves, so that your fresh install of Windows 2000 will have LBA48 support enabled from the beginning. To do this you would use REGEDT32 to open SETUPREG.HIV in the i386 directory from the Windows 2000 CD, and add the same registry entry there.

Comment: In this case, is it the partition that setup is running from that the size matters or the whole drive itself?

Comment: @the_electro_bros - The partition size is the main issue, as the entire thing needs to be addressable using LBA28 if you want to use that. Creating a small partition at the beginning of a large disk can work, but sometimes there are obscure issues that still foul it up.

Answer (score 4):

Win 2K has no support for sata devices, so when it switches to protected mode, the device becomes inacessable, and cant boot.

The same is true for XP, you must supply the sata driver via a floppy disk, (usb floppy drive ok since at this point the bios will emulate a floppy, but usb sticks will not work) or slipstream it onto the installation cd, this true for all controllers.

You need to hit the appropriate key during the installation, when it asks about mass storage devices. Annoyingly the prompt is just before it starts copying files and only available for a few seconds.

Win XP drivers and win2k are sometimes interchangable, if win2k drivers are not available.

If the boaard manufacturer does not have sata drivers, intel has reference ones for many chipsets.

Otherwise you are out of luck

Comment: The asker mentioned IDE compatibility mode is enabled in BIOS settings; isn’t that provided at the controller level usually? Why wouldn’t it work?

Comment: it will work only until the protected mode switch, hence the first part of the installer will run, and win 98 could run aince it can do disk access bia bios calls. 32 bit os, nt 2k xp and later cant

Comment: But 16-bit disk interrupt services have to be provided even without an explicit IDE compatibility mode. Many bootloaders are downright hardcoded to use those services, at least in initial stages, and will not work otherwise. So what does the IDE compatibility switch really set? I imagine it’s emulation at the controller level, which doesn’t care for real versus protected mode. Am I wrong?

Comment: once you are in 32 bit mode, the bios can perform no further action. Its not as if win2k will fit on any actual IDE drive, as opposed to an ata one. win2k must operate in ata mode, or it cant see the device. This is unfortunate if it cant detect the ata controller

Comment: I also dont know how even in principle this could be emulated - anything over 128gb needs lba48, and that didnt come out until 2002, im pretty sure win2k doesnt support that either In the days of win2k we used scsi if we needed a high capacity drive. Sure a controller could in principle support emulation, but ive never seen it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right. Disk size, yes, but in all computers I've used that had an "IDE/AHCI" switch, the emulated IDE interface remained visible the entire time, even within a 32-bit or 64-bit OS (while the AHCI interface disappeared from lspci) – so it's definitely not BIOS-level emulation, but rather the BIOS telling the controller itself to switch into a different mode, or something such. (That is, Windows 10 would see an IDE disk and wouldn't use its StorAhci driver, etc.)

Comment: "once you are in 32 bit mode, the bios can perform no further action" Technically, not entirely true in SMM-enabled systems (though SMM would likely incur far too much of a performance penalty to use it for disk access. It is used though to provide "USB legacy support" for input devices etc. )

Comment: "IDE drive, as opposed to an ata one." These aren't entirely different protocols (ATAPI is another matter, *but not used for hard drives*).... Is your intent to distinguish "old school", WD-1003 emulating, CHS based systems from LBA-enabled versions?

Comment: It should be possible to test whether the real problem is a disk size limit: Old 32/64/120 GByte SSDs that connect to SATA should be cheaply and easily available,

Comment: Interestingly, I installed XP and it worked just fine. However, the way I did it was by creating a Windows 7 PE, and then running the installer from there. Could this be viable for Win2K?

Comment: Dont actually know. If you want to do this install a quick google search for win2000 universal sata driver brings up things that seem designed for exactly what you are trying to do, which will also solve the LBA48 problem as well, and is almost certainly the way to go. If however you need win2k because some  controller pc has died and needs to run 2k, then I'd probably acquire  hardware that better matches the original.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe you have answered your own question here.  Apart from an actual failed boot device, which seems unlikely here, the usual reason is that the required device driver is no loaded for Windows.

Many common (in the day) devices were inherently supported by Windows or the devices had a "compatibility" mode to allow them to operate, often at a lower performance level, in order to boot Windows.  But there were devices then, and probably more now, where there is no compatibility mode and there was no built-in support in Windows 2000.

You will need to find a driver for this device, assuming one exists, and install it into your boot image so that Windows can find it during initialization.

Note that it could be either the SATA hard drive itself or it could be the hard drive controller/interface which is likely on the motherboard.  I'd start with the motherboard manufacturer.  A big problem now is that newer hardware rarely has support for obsolete systems like Windows 2000.  So you may be out-of-luck on this one.