# Why does Windows ME setup not start even if I switch SATA drives to IDE mode?

Tags: ide, windows-me

I switched SATA disks to IDE emulation mode in the BIOS (instead of AHCI).  Then I ran Windows ME setup from a SATA CD drive. But I get this error:

> Device driver not found: OEMCD001  
> No valid CDROM device drivers selected

This error message is common if you try to run the setup from an AHCI SATA CD drive. Because Windows ME does not support AHCI.

My question is: Why am I still getting this message even though I switched from AHCI to IDE mode?

I tried two different CD drives. Maybe they don't support IDE mode. But I do not know how to check it.

I know there is an AHCI driver around. But I want to know why it doesn't work even though I switched to IDE mode.

I found [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/windows-2000-inaccessible-boot-device-when-running-setup-from-sata-hard-drive) post but it is about a different error.

Edit:
I found out when I run the setup on an old PC (on which it is working) I get this line (under the CD drive info of the Windows setup):

```
Transfer Mode: Programmed I/O
```

I know this mode is also simply called PIO mode. On a modern PC with a SATA CD drive in IDE mode this line is missing.

Edit:
Here is the screenshot. I get this error even if SATA mode is set to IDE.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is your SATA drive plugged to one of the SATA ports that can be set to IDE mode? Because not all SATA ports can be set to IDE mode.

Comment: @Justme Good idea but did not work. I have 4 SATA ports. Port 1 is white and the others are yellow. I tried all yellow ports and got the same error. On port 1 it does not boot at all. Not in AHCI mode and not in IDE mode. Seems port 1 only accepts HDDs.

Comment: Does ME require the CD operate in floppy emulation mode?

Comment: @another-dave Possibly. Do modern mainboards (2010+) support floppy emulation CDROMs?

Comment: @another-dave As I remember, yes. Windows 9x CDs were probably the chief user of it.

Comment: @somega Floppy emulation is not a matter of the CD drive or the mainboard as such, but rather of BIOS support for the appropriate boot protocol. Newer BIOS firmware (i.e. pre-EFI) that supports CD booting at all usually supports floppy emulation just fine… I think. The fact that the CD driver managed to load at all (if only to show an error) seems to confirm floppy emulation works fine in your case.

Comment: I found out the problem might be that PIO mode is not available (see my edit). Does anyone know how to get PIO mode work on a modern PC?

Comment: I'd assume the drive is not detected at all rather than that the PIO mode is not available (which in fact is very basic and simple to provide). Can you show us boot messages in full? You can use the [Pause/Break] key to prevent messages from disappearing before you write down or photograph them.

Comment: As a workaround, I'd suggest making a bootable USB stick with some version of DOS (FreeDOS or MS-DOS 7.x/8.x) and the [UIDE](https://ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/repositories/1.3/drivers/uide.zip) driver, which supports DMA and is therefore faster than the OAKCDROM driver bundled with Windows 9x.

Comment: @user3840170 As I already wrote in the question I know that there are drivers around. I wanted to get an unmodified Windows CD to run.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: As expected, the drive is not detected by the driver at all, leading to MSCDEX failing further along the line. Diagnosing this without physical access (and e.g. running arbitrary diagnostic software) looks rather dire, though it might still help to know if an alternative CD driver would work…